# Loading value in UITableViewController from async task

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a problem trying to load a UITableViewController.

I have an async task that is called in the **loadView** method. This async task works well and results are returned as I expect.

The problem is, the app fail when trying to populate the TableView.

I suspect that it's due to the fact that my data are not completely loaded when the method are called.

Is there anyway to force the TableView to wait on my async task to be finished ?

The function that loads my data:

```
func loadNetInformations(){
    var postString: NSString = "info=all"

    HTTPGet("myurl", "POST", postString){
        (data: NSArray, error:String?)-> Void in
        if error != nil{
            println(error)
        }
        else{
            for value in data{
                var sService: NSString = "some value"

                var aContent: NSArray = value["Content"] as NSArray

                var sNumberCount: NSNumber = aContent.count

                self.aListeService.addObject(sService)
                self.aSizeOfDpt.addObject(sNumberCount)
                self.aContenuListes.addObject(aContent)

                self.bFinishLoading = true

            } // End for in HTTPGet
        } // End else in HTTPGet
    } // End HTTPGet

} // End LoadNet Information
```

My HTTPGet method is as following:

```
func HTTPSendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest,
callback: (NSArray, String?) -> Void){
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {

            callback (NSArray(), error.localizedDescription)
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        else{
            callback(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)! as NSArray, nil)

        }


    }
    task.resume()
}


func HTTPGet(url: String, requestMethod: String, postString: String, callback: (NSArray, String?) -> Void){
     var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = requestMethod
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    HTTPSendRequest(request, callback)
}
```

EDIT: Ok now I don't have the error anymore (I used a NSString as an NSInteger...) but it doesn't show anything

EDIT2: 
here's my JSON format in case it can help:

```
[
  {
    "CodeAbsence" : "6000", 
    "Content" : 
                [
                  {
                    "Init":"DAS",
                    "Nom":"Name",
                    "Prenom":"Firstname",
                    "IdAbsence":"619",
                    "TimbreusePresent":"O",
                    "TimbreuseHeure":"14:44",
                    "TimbreuseRaison":"0",
                    "TimbreuseDate":"",
                    "CodeAbsence":"6000",
                    "Telephone":"248"
                   },
                    ....
               ]
  },
   .......
 ]
```

Comment: Is `loadNetInformaion` in your `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Yes it is, but I've tried without calling this function and it doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem. It was coming from the use of `viewDidLoad()` instead of `viewDidAppear()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the tableView to trigger a table update and you need to trigger it on the main UI thread.

```
        for value in data{
            var sService: NSString = "some value"

            var aContent: NSArray = value["Content"] as NSArray

            var sNumberCount: NSNumber = aContent.count

            self.aListeService.addObject(sService)
            self.aSizeOfDpt.addObject(sNumberCount)
            self.aContenuListes.addObject(aContent)

            self.bFinishLoading = true
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            } 
        }
```

When you perform an asynchronous operation on a background thread your callback is still going to run on the background thread, so always be sure to switch back to the main thread before performing any UI task.

Comment: I had an error in my loadNetInformation trying to convert NSString to NSInteger the hardway... Now it works but it's black. When I add the dispatch_async as you suggest it failed with error: found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: most likely the `nil` value is coming from the tableView. I can't help you anymore unless you provide more context into your viewController. Is it a UITableViewController or is this a UIViewController acting as a UITableViewDelegate for an IBOutlet UITableView?

Comment: It is an UITableViewController

Comment: That's strange. Do you have a link to your project I can look at?

Comment: I can't share the whole projet but here's the link to the related class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pw6fq99ik9lqd4j/ListePersonnelTableViewController_debug.swift?dl=0

Comment: move  `self.loadNetInformations()` to `viewDidLoad`--you don't have access to `self.tableView` before that.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {self.tableView.reloadData()}`, and also put a breakpoint on ` func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and see what this function returns.

Comment: What isn't working?--are you getting the same error message, 'nil value on tableView' or a new one?

Comment: Blacksquare: still the same error, yes

chuthan20: it doesn't reach the second breakpoint. The error append before it.

I also noticed that loadview and viewdidload are called multiple times (approximatively 10 times each), is it normal ?

Comment: Go into storyboard and ensure that the dataSource and delegate of your UITableView are linked to your controller.

Comment: Seems to be well connected. I've reconnected to be sure and still this error.

Comment: Okay, found what was the problem. I've moved my call of loadNetInformations() into viedDidAppear() instead of viewDidLoad() - Thanks for your help!